# webservice - does http connection pool make sense?

Tags: java, web-services, httpclient

I'm in the progress of implementing a webservice server and client with apache cxf, after reading this [HTTP Connection Pooling discussion](http://cxf.547215.n5.nabble.com/HTTP-Connection-Pooling-td561783.html), i'm really confuse about this. Does pooling http connection make sense? Since both client and server cannot keep the connection for a while.

Thank you.

Edited: the comment below clearly answer the question. Thank you murdoch!

Comment: You may want to elaborate a little on what you are trying to achieve as its difficult to give an answer to this but in the mean time, i would suggest reading up on HTTP Keep Alive.

Comment: @murdoch: Since your comment seems to answer the question, please move it to an answer so that robinmag can accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, Well it seems you have done the reading and the answer is to enable HTTP Keep Alive.